# What is the cause for the Japanese people’s exemplary civility?

Tags: behavior

Japanese people should certainly be commended for their exemplary displays of civility, I’m sure this doesn’t require debating ([this scholarly source](https://youtu.be/hj1VfnJdRNw) including examples like respecting subway stair lanes, leaving a lost shopping bag beside a tree and a hotel apologizing for a 4-am 1-minute Internet shortage). However, **I am genuinely curious what the psychological cause for said civility would be**. Has there perhaps been a time in Japan’s history when this wasn’t the case from which we could infer an origin for such high and seemingly nationwide standards?

Comment: If anyone has the power to do that, I would appreciate the adding of some relevant tags like japan, respect, civility!

Comment: This should probably be in sociology or culture stack exchange.

Comment: There is no sociology or culture stack that I'm aware of.  The history stack exchange might be better.  Either way, this question is too opinion-based for this forum.